# phpmyadmin showing php script

Tags: php, linux, apache, phpmyadmin

Well, I am having problem while installing `phpmyadmin` to my linux system. I followed all the instruction from digital ocean. After, I verify it in the browser then it shows this kind of `php code`.
Did I miss something during my installation? My version of php is 7 and I am using ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/55280/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it

Comment: Maybe u r using Php tag without Php `<? ?>` if yes change it to `<?Php ?>`

Comment: In case this helps someone else, I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 and when trying to bring up phpmyadmin at `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin`, php source code was being shown. Took a while to figure out the fix, which is below.
1. phpmyadmin.conf file location is at `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf`.
2. Add Apache Include statement that indicates where phpmyadmin.conf file can be found.
2a. # File: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
2b. Include /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
3. `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` does display phpMyAdmin interface now.

Comment: @Chris yours is the correct answer

Answer (score 19):

Its seems that your server(Apache) is not recognizing php script as `PHP` language to be executed. At first check whether `PHP` is enable or not by running the following command in your terminal:

`a2query -m php7.0`

If it says somathing like `PHP` is not enable then run the following command:

`sudo a2enmod php7.0`

Then restart your `Apache2` server with the following command:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Try refreshing the phpmyadmin page now. Hope this will solve your problem. Best of luck

Comment: This one works for me `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: or just use ***sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php*** if you are not sure of the version. This worked for php8.0

Comment: i can recommend this. because it worked me also `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`

Answer (score 2):

After you install php for (I'm assuming) Apache you need to restart the webserver for it to read the config files.

Comment: tbh, had to go through a lot of fixes and retries before, but this answer was the last thing that needed to be done.

Comment: Can't believe this worked for me, gosh I'm embarrassed.