# Laravel won't register user in Users Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to work on a Laravel PHP project and as I am new to this framework. First step I had to do is build a Registration Form. **However, when I click on the Submit button no error is given, and nothing is registered in my users table.**

Here is the code for my project so far :

**My users migration table up and down functions**

```
 public function up()
      {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->boolean('sexe');
            $table->integer('age');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }

I added to the original two fields which are : "sexe a boolean F/M" and age
```

**My RegisterController important functions**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/register';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required', 'string', 'max:255',
            'sexe'=> 'required|in:male,female',
            'age' => 'required|integer|max:100',
            'email' => 'required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users',
            'password' => 'required', 'string', 'min:5', 'confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'sexe' => $data['sexe'],
            'age' => $data['age'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

    }


  /**
     * Override default register method from RegistersUsers trait
     *
     * @param array $request
     * @return redirect to $redirectTo
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        //add activation_key to the $request array
        $activation_key = $this->getToken();
        $request->request->add(['activation_key' => $activation_key]);

        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        //$this->guard()->login($user);

        //write a code for send email to a user with activation link
        $data = array('name' => $request['name'], 'email' => $request['email'],  'activation_link' => url('/activation/' . $activation_key));

        Mail::send('emails.mail', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to($data['email'])
                    ->subject('Activate Your Account');
            $message->from('s.sajid@artisansweb.net');
        });

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('success', 'We have sent an activation link on your email id. Please verify your account.');
                        print_r($request->input());
    }

}
```

**My Routes**

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@create');
Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@register');
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**My User.php Model fillable**

protected $fillable = [
        'name','sexe','age','email','password',
    ];

```
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

}

**My blade file register part (register.blade.php)**

```
 <body>


                                    <form method="POST" role="form" action="//IJJI/resources/views/chat.blade.php">
                                    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                                                <input id="name" name="name"type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez ici votre Pseudo *" value="" />

                                                    <label class="radio inline"> 
                                                        <input id="homme" type="radio" name="sexe" value="homme" checked>
                                                        <span> Homme </span> 
                                                    </label>
                                                    <label class="radio inline"> 
                                                        <input id="femme" type="radio" name="sexe" value="femme">
                                                        <span>Femme </span> 
                                                    </label>

                                                <input id="age" name="age" type="integer" class="form-control" placeholder="Saisissez votre age *" value="" />
                                                <input id="Email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Saisissez votre Email *" value="" />

                                                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez votre Mot de Passe *" value="" />

                                                <input id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confrimez votre Mot de Passe *" value="" />

                                            <button type="submit" class="btnRegister">
                                                Je deviens membre Gratuitement
                                            </button>

                                    </form>

            </body>
```

I have done PHP artisan make auth generated the files, made `.env` file adequate to my MySQL database with the username and password, even checked the PhpMyAdmin configuration, but all in vain.

After 4 days of search in Google websites I can't figure out where I am wrong.

P.S : Another thing that could be wrong is that code like this :

```
@section
@endsection
```

never gets accepted and just shows like normal text on my browser.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MartinHeralecký It's complete and minimal won't help the community get the error , because when i provide minimal stuff people ask to see other files. Besides if i knew where the problem is coming from i wouldn't have asked. Plus what if i provide the wrong file all the files here can contain the problem. So i don't know how to provide a minimal stuff

Comment: How to make it "minimal" is described in the link I posted. I.e. _"start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back"_.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký here i removed some of the code i kept only snipets of every file there

Comment: Great. Please also remove the unnecessary HTML code and allign it properly so it's well-readable (keep only the form, inputs and buttons (no `<div>`s are necessary)).

Comment: @MartinHeralecký Sir here i formatted the text and removed all the divs

Comment: Why is `sexe` a boolean field?

Comment: @kerbholz i made it string but no changes so far

Comment: Please if anyone got any idea

Answer (score 0):

Check your laravel logs location: storage/logs you will get errors.

i have notice you are using  $table->boolean('sexe') and in validation you are giving string boolen should be 0/1

```
'sexe'=> 'required:in:true,false',
```

also change in your html form to 0,1  currently you are using male, female

Comment: thanks for you answer first, i made the changes for the radiobutton, however i already checked my storage/logs , it contains files that date from yesterday. The problem is still there here today the 03/02 and no files of todays date.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting error? 
Besides, can you please the following line at the top of your form to see if there is any validation error or not. After that try submitting the form and see if there is any error or not!

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div style="color:red">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
            <ul>
                <li>{{$message}}</li>
            </ul>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

And remove the action form the form tags.
Use: 
`@csrf`

or

`{{csrf_field()}}`

instead of

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: thank you first, however a strange behavior happens when i try to implements code like "@ if" ... all the "@ if" lines or @ content or @ yield just appear as normal text in my browser. Even using the {{csrf_field()}} makes it just appear on the browser as normal text that is why i wrote <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: Check out this thread if this is the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806051/phpmyadmin-showing-php-script/39809762#39809762

Comment: thanks for your answer i tried to check this but still failed